Proving bijectivity of Riehl's Exercise 1.5.i categorically
I am trying to solve Riehl's Category Theory in Context, exercise 1.5.i, and I ran into a problem. The problem is as follows:
Exercise: Fixing a parallel pair of functors $F, G : C \rightrightarrows D$, natural transformations $\alpha : F \Rightarrow G$ correspond bijectively to functors $H : C \times 2 \to D$ such that $H$ restricts along $\iota_0$ and $\iota_1$ to the functors $F$ and $G$, i.e., so that

commutes. (Does MathSE support commutative diagrams in latex?) Here $2$ is the category with two objects $\{0, 1\}$ and an arrow $0 \to 1$.
My solution is the same as this, defining functions $\alpha \mapsto H$ and $H \mapsto \alpha$, and proving they are inverses of each other via computing the images of objects and morphisms etc. However, I found this unsatisfying, as in category theory, (from what I know) one wants to avoid looking at objects at all, and focus on morphisms and diagrams (their relations). When proving the functions are inverses, I had to do a lot of case work too, e.g. proving $H(C, 0 \to 0)$ and $H(C, 0 \to 1)$ and $H(C, 1 \to 1)$ satisfy properties. So my question is is there a more "categorical" way to solve this exercise?
I got an idea from a friend to think of $\mathrm{Hom}(C \times 2, D) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(2, D^C)$, which correspond to arrows in $D^C$. But I don't understand how to proceed.

(MathSE supports amscd, but not tikzcd, see here. Embedding your diagrams as pictures is also generally accepted, however)

You only have to prove 2 things now: 1. For any category $\mathcal{C}$, a functor $2 \to \mathcal{C}$ is the same as a choice of morphism of $\mathcal{C}$ (i.e. $\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}\Hom_{\mathrm{Cat}}(2, \mathcal{C}) \cong \operatorname{mor} \mathcal{C}$, at least if $\mathcal{C}$ is small), i.e. that $2$ is the "walking arrow," in Riehl's terminology, and 2. that a natural transformation between functors $F, G\colon \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ is the same as a morphism in $\mathcal{D}^{\mathcal{C}}$.

@BenSteffan Thanks for the amscd tip. For (1) That $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Cat}}(2, C) \cong \mathrm{mor}(C)$, I guess it's because a functor $F : 2 \Rightarrow C$ must satisfy $F(0 \to 1) = F(0) \to F(1)$, and the opposite direction is easy. For (2) is it just by definition?

Also sorry if this is somewhat trivial, but where is the commutative diagram now then?

@GarethMa also, here you can only make square diagrams, but not triangles. It's pretty annoying.

@GarethMa If you've established that a functor $H\colon 2 \to \mathcal{D}^{\mathcal{C}}$ is the same data as a nat. trans. from $H(0)$ to $H(1)$, then you restrict to only those functors $H$ with $H(0) = F$, $H(1) = G$, from which you can get your diagram back by unraveling the isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal{C} \times 2, \mathcal{D}) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(2, \mathcal{D}^{\mathcal{C}})$; this would be a good exercise to do yourself :)
